# Coverting a csv-file to a PHP 2D-array

Tags: php, html, arrays, file, csv

I'm new at PHP and keep struggling to read a CSV file into a 2D-array. I use the following file 'csv/team.csv':

```
ID,Nickname,Shirtnumber,Position
1,Jimmy,0,RightBack
2,Mark,3,CentreBack
3,Bryan,17,LeftMidfielder
4,James,23,Striker
5,Andre,69,Goalkeeper
```

I would like to be able to:

1. display the 'name', 'shirtnumber', 'position' etc. of individual
   players on a html/css-webpage.
2. use the PHP-functions `prev()`, `current()`, `next()` to navigate between players.
3. use associative keys (besides indexed keys).

My first piece of code looked like this:

```
    $teamdata = file("csv/team.csv");
    foreach ($teamdata as $playerline) {
            $player = explode(",", $playerline);
            list($ID,$Nickname,$Shirtnumber,$Position) = $player;
    { 
    print_r($player); echo "<br>";
    print_r(prev($player)); echo "<br>";
```

The result in HTML was:

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => Andre [2] => 69 [3] => Goalkeeper )
```

This looks pretty cool. However,

1. Why does `list()` not add associative keys to the array?
2. Why does `prev()` not work? (PHP didn't give any error-message or warning)

By introducing `$myplayer`, I created an array of `$player`.

```
    $teamdata = file("csv/team.csv");
    foreach ($teamdata as $playerline) {
            $player = explode(",", $playerline);
            list($ID,$Nickname,$Shirtnumber,$Position) =$player;
        $myplayer[]=$player;
}   

    print_r($player); echo "<br>"; echo "<br>";
    print_r($myplayer); echo "<br>";echo "<br>";

    echo $player[1]; echo "<br>";
    echo $player[3]; echo "<br>"; echo "<br>";
    echo $myplayer[1][1]; echo "<br>";
    echo $myplayer[2][1]; echo "<br>";
```

The output looked like:

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => Andre [2] => 69 [3] => Goalkeeper ) 

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ID [1] => Nickname [2] => Shirtnumber [3] => Position ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Jimmy [2] => 0 [3] => RightBack ) 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => Mark [2] => 3 [3] => CentreBack ) 
        [3] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => Bryan [2] => 17 [3] => LeftMidfielder ) 
        [4] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => James [2] => 23 [3] => Striker ) 
        [5] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => Andre [2] => 69 [3] => Goalkeeper ) ) 

Andre
Goalkeeper

Jimmy
Mark
```

This seems pretty much what I needed. However. I ask myself if this is the right way to do it, because:

1. The function `list()` can't be used
2. The function `prev()` can't be used
3. Coding for selecting the correct 'player-attribute' is 'complex' and errors can easily be made

I have a background in programming COBOL (lol) and Pascal, but PHP (and Java) is totally new for me. Any advise would be welcome!

Comment: What is the purpose of `prev` and `next` I'm not getting it.

Comment: Thank your for your quick reaction. I want to use functions such as prev(), current() and next() to make conditional statements.

Comment: If you can expand on that with pseudo code or flow/objective I can add it.

Comment: Im not this far yet really, I try to get my arrays on order first. However, I'm thinking about conditions such as: if (current($myplayer)==end($myplayer)) {reset($myplayer}

Comment: Okay, this works perfect for me, exactly what I was looking for. I can also use next() and prev() now. I didn't realize the pointer was at the first array element. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `list` just assigns array values to variables.

You probably want to extract the headings first and combine that with each row to get an associative array:

```
$teamdata = file("csv/team.csv", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
//get and remove first line to use as keys
$headings = str_getcsv(array_shift($teamdata));

foreach ($teamdata as $playerline) {
        $player = str_getcsv($playerline);
        //combine keys with values
        $result[] = array_combine($headings, $player);
{
```

2. You call `prev` on the array, however the array pointer is already at the first element so there is no previous and it returns `false`.  This is seen with: `var_dump(prev($result));`

Comment: So there was a PHP function to parse csv! Cannot underestimate PHP standard library... Comments on the doc page are inspiring, worth reading: http://php.net/str_getcsv

Answer (score 1):

I think [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) comment contains [very laconic solution](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#117692), although it can be improved by using [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) `$userdata` parameter:

```
array_walk($teamdata, function(&$player, $_, $headers) {
    $player = array_combine($headers, $player);
}, array_shift($teamdata));
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a02c058e7ac5f857aa6779c7efbe2e3c9de7313c).

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect aswell. Only a bit harder to understand for a newbie as myself.